# How to replace every non-alphanumeric char with a space in Mysql?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

So, I would need a function to do that. So far I have found some answers for deleting the non-alphanumeric characters but I cannot manage to replace them with spaces....
for example `select alpha("THOMAS-THOMAS")` would give me THOMAS THOMAS as a result

Comment: update your question add a proper data sample and the expected result

Comment: Where's your query???  Learn how to ask question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It's not easy to do with the built-in functions in MySQL. Google for a regexp replace UDF.